# Edit!!! Blackjack game creation in Python, error occurred while it played

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, blackjack

The code worked, but the results were not what I want to get.

Blackjack game is supposed to provide 'A' as 1 or 11, but it was not working

By some reasons, if I 'h' (hit) the card, it won't let me go back to 's'(stand)

If I got blackjack, dealer opened card again even though dealer did not get a blackjack.

There might be other problem.... I have no idea :(

I am not familiar with def, so I might try to learn def again next time..

I really want to solve this problem..

```
import random

card_dict = {'A': 11, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

cardcolor = ['S', 'H', 'C', 'D']


def player_draw():
    return random.choice(list(card_dict))

def dealer_draw():
    return random.choice(list(card_dict))

player_color = random.choice(cardcolor)
dealer_color = random.choice(cardcolor)

player_score = 0
dealer_score = 0

player_cards = []

while True:
    player_card = []
    player_card.append(player_draw())
    player_card.append(player_draw())
    print('your cards:',player_card[0]+player_color,player_card[1]+player_color)
    player_total = card_dict[player_card[0]]+card_dict[player_card[1]] 

    dealer_card = []
    dealer_card.append(dealer_draw())
    dealer_card.append(dealer_draw())

    dealer_cards = []

    for i in dealer_card:
        dealer_cards.append(card_dict[i])

    dealer_total = sum(dealer_cards)    

    stand_hit = input('(S)tand or (H)it?...: ')



    if player_total == 21:
        if dealer_total != 21:
            print('Blackjack!')
            player_score += 1
            print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
            play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')

            if play_again == 'y':
                print()
            elif play_again == 'n':
                print('\n')
                break
        elif dealer_total == 21:
            print('It is too bad')


    if stand_hit == 's':

        print('Dealer cards:', dealer_card[0]+dealer_color, dealer_card[1]+dealer_color)

        if dealer_total >= 17:

            if dealer_total > player_total:
                print('Dealer wins')
                dealer_score += 1
                print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                if play_again == 'y':
                    print()
                    continue
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    print('\n')
                    break

            elif dealer_total == player_total:
                print('Draw')
                print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                if play_again == 'y':
                    print()
                    continue
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    print('\n')
                    break

            elif dealer_total < player_total:
                print('You win!')
                player_score += 1
                print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)

                play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                if play_again == 'y':
                    print()
                    continue
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    print('\n')
                    break
        elif dealer_total < 17:
            while dealer_total < 17:
                if player_total or dealer_total < 11:
                    card_dict['A'] = 11

                elif player_total or dealer_total > 10:
                    card_dict['A'] = 1

                a = random.choice(list(card_dict))
                print('Dealer drew:', a + dealer_color)
                dealer_total += card_dict[a]

                if dealer_total > 21:
                    print('You win!')
                    player_score += 1
                    print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                    play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                    if play_again == 'y':
                        print()
                        continue
                    elif play_again == 'n':
                        print('\n')
                        break

                elif dealer_total <= 21:
                    if dealer_total > player_total:
                        print('Dealer wins')
                        dealer_score += 1
                        print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                        play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                        if play_again == 'y':
                            print()
                            continue
                        elif play_again == 'n':
                            print('\n')
                            break

                    elif dealer_total == player_total:
                        print('Draw')
                        print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                        play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                        if play_again == 'y':
                            print()
                            continue
                        elif play_again == 'n':
                            print('\n')
                            break

                    elif dealer_total < player_total:
                        print('You win!')
                        player_score += 1
                        print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)

                        play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                        if play_again == 'y':
                            print()
                            continue
                        elif play_again == 'n':
                            print('\n')
                            break


    elif stand_hit == 'h':

        if player_total or dealer_total < 11:
            card_dict['A'] = 11

        elif player_total or dealer_total > 10:
            card_dict['A'] = 1

        a_cards = random.choice(list(card_dict))
        print('You drew:', a_cards + player_color) 
        player_total += card_dict[a_cards]

        if player_total > 21:
            print('Dealer wins')
            dealer_score += 1
            print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
            play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
            if play_again == 'y':
                print()
                continue
            elif play_again == 'n':
                print('\n')
                break
        elif player_total <= 21:

            stand_hit = input('(S)tand or (H)it?...: ')
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. In Blackjack, aren't the player and dealer initially dealt two cards?  Why are you randomizing 4 cards for the initialization? Additionally, you have a glaring issue being that players can draw the same card. For example, it is technically possible for all 8 randomized cards to be Ace of Spades.

Comment: @Sri Hi! Thank you for your comment, What I want to do is to pick up random cards whenever players or dealers want to pick up new cards, but if I am using only one random sentence like " random.choice(list(card_dict))", players and dealers pick always same cards up. I want to know how to pick up cards randomly in while-loop. Does it make sense to you :(?

Comment: @Sri, A reason for 4 cards is that if sum of dealers' cards or players' cards are less than 15, for player, they are more likely picking up new cards, and for dealers, they are supposed to pick up new cards until sum of cards are greater than 17

Comment: To avoid picking up the same card, put the already picked up cards in a set. When you "pick up" a new card, check if it exists in the set. If it does exist, randomize another card.

Comment: Could you give me an example for me :(?

Comment: I understand your logic for picking up 4 cards, but it is technically incorrect. What if the dealer picks up all of the "2" cards. Their total value is 8, and they would want to draw another. This is why you have to incorporate randomly drawing again in the loop.

Comment: @Sri, That's exactly what I want to say and do! That's what I am having trouble with :( I have no idea about it

Comment: @Sri, I updated!

Comment: Your logic for printing cards is wrong. Look at the example I posted in my answer as to how to print cards. You do not need to use player_color or dealer_color anymore. They are incorporated in the drawCard function.

Answer (score 0):

A program like this requires a base to work off of. I have created a simple base and some simple functions that will allow you to do things like draw cards, print cards, and get the sum of a players cards (while avoiding duplicates in all scenarios). You should be able to figure out the logic as to when a player/dealer should draw another card.

```
import random

card_dict = {'A': 11, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

cardcolor = ['S', 'H', 'C', 'D']

#We define an empty list for three sets of cards. A players cards, a dealers cards, and all drawn cards
player_cards = []
dealer_cards = []
drawn_cards = []

player_score = 0
dealer_score = 0

# This is a function that will draw a card and add it to a list
def drawCard(cardlist):
    player_card = (random.choice(list(card_dict)), random.choice(cardcolor))
    while player_card in drawn_cards:
        player_card = (random.choice(list(card_dict)), random.choice(cardcolor))
    cardlist.append(player_card)
    drawn_cards.append(player_card)

# This is a simple function to convert a card tuple to a string
def printCard(card):
    return card[0] + card[1]

def printCards(cardlist):
    cards = ""
    for card in cardlist:
        cards += printCard(card) + " "
    return cards



# This is a function to return the total value of a list of cards
def getTotalValue(cards):
    total_sum = 0
    for card in cards:
        total_sum += card_dict[card[0]]
    return total_sum

# Draw 2 for player
for i in range(2):
    drawCard(player_cards)

# Draw 2 for dealer
for i in range(2):
    drawCard(dealer_cards)

# If you want to print players cards
print('Players cards: ', printCards(player_cards))

# If you want to print dealer cards
print('Dealer cards: ', printCards(dealer_cards))

# If you want to draw a card for player
drawCard(player_cards)
# If you want to draw a card for dealer
drawCard(dealer_cards)

#If you want to get the sum of players cards
player_total = getTotalValue(player_cards)

#If you want to get sum of dealers cards
dealer_total = getTotalValue(dealer_cards)
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! May I ask you one more question?

Comment: I am not familiar with definition, so What am I supposed to write in cardlist? in def drawcard(cardlist):

Comment: Sure! This site is for asking questions. A definition is a function. If you look later on in the code, we see we are calling drawCard(player_cards). That means draw a card and add it to the players list. Alternatively we can call drawCard(dealer_cards)

Comment: Thanks! I got it, so don't I need to use while-loop for it? I am still confused :(

Comment: You would still need to use a while-loop. In that loop, perform your blackjack logic. When dealer needs to draw a card, call drawCard(dealer_cards). When you want to find the total value of a dealers cards, call getTotalValue(dealer_cards).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it! I really appreciate it

Comment: I tried, but it gave me same cards again and again whenever I stand :(

Comment: HI! Sri!, Despite you helped me a lot, I tried to work defs which you provided, I had no idea how to use it because I am very very newbie in Python.. I tried to learn those about 3 hours last night, and I gave up :( I will study those as hard as I can later. But! Because I am a person who cannot wait until the problem that I have is solved, so I write a cord for 4 hours after I gave up def code. I edited my code again, and if you have some time, could you look at and what problems are there....? Right now, I have totally no idea what problems I have...

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and It helped me a lot understanding def!!!!!!!